# Comparator IC IN+ changing after voltage divider

Tags: voltage-divider, comparator, parasitic-capacitance

I have a battery that is charged to about 6.85V, this is the "batteryvoltage" input. Due to the voltage divider on IN+ I read 1.7V at the comparator. But when I plug in a separate wired 12V source elsewhere on the circuit board, this same battery begins to measure 1.9V or 1.7V at times at the comparator, but the actual battery voltage does not change.  Is this parasitic capacitance?  I imagine that I will need to decrease the impedance of the voltage divider, but to what level?  [Comparator](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tlv3401)

[image: circuit]

The 12V source is used to charge the battery.  But in this state the charging is disabled, the EN is disabled for the charging ICs.  So I don't suspect this second circuit has much interaction.

[image]

Comment: Show the rest of your schematic.

Comment: If BatteryVoltage increases, obviously IN+ will increase. Reducing the impedance of the voltage divider does not help. You'll need to understand how the 12V source is pulling up the battery voltage and fix that. Rest of the schematic is hence needed.

Comment: I have edited the post, but I am saying that the battery voltage doesn't change when I plug in the 12V wired connection, just the voltage measured at the comparator.

Comment: Where do you plug in 12 V?

Comment: Do you mean layout wise?  I have just posted the full schematics of how these two traces interact.

Comment: Somehow the comparator trips and the positive feedback via R5 lifts the voltage at IN+ above the threshold. Try 100 pF in parallel to R3 to catch transients.